# Why question mark instead of text in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PHP 5.3.3

IF i try PDO i saw Russian text like "?????? ?????????"

```
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $DBData['host'] . ';dbname=' . $DBData['base'] . ";charset=utf8;", 
        $DBData['user'], $DBData['pass'], array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT         => true
    ));

    $CONFIG = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `config`")->fetch();
```

If i try this i saw normal text:

```
    $db = mysql_connect($DBData['host'], $DBData['user'], $DBData['pass']);
    mysql_select_db($DBData['base'], $db);
    mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8', $db);          
    mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8', $db);  
    mysql_query('SET COLLATION_CONNECTION="utf8"', $db);

    $CONFIG = mysql_fetch_assoc( mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `config`") );
```

Why PDO didn`t work

Comment: Use `setAttribute(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND, 'SET NAMES utf8'`

Comment: @Fred-ii- thx, it`s work)

Comment: welcome, glad to hear it